# Oracle DECODE and NVL

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to analyze an existing oracle query. I am not well versed in Oracle and I'm bit confused by the use of this NVL function in DECODE function

```
Select 
DECODE (DECODE(NVL(tab.id,0),0,0,1)+ DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,01), 2,'two', 0,'none',
DECODE (DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,0,1),1,'one','NA')
) Result
```

The tables are contains below values.

```
Tab
count   id
1   1111
0   null
1   2222
1   3333
1   4444
1   5555
    
tab2    
count   id
1   1111
1   3333
1   6666
1   2222
0   null
```

How does a DECODE function work here?

Comment: I am assuming that you have a typo and `DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,01)` should be `DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,0,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does a `DECODE` function work here?

`DECODE` is a function-based equivalent of a `CASE` statement.

Your code is the equivalent of:

```sql
Select CASE DECODE(NVL(tab.id,0),0,0,1)
            + DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,0,1),
       WHEN 2 THEN 'two'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'none'
       ELSE DECODE(DECODE (NVL(tab2.id,0),0,0,1),1,'one','NA')
       END AS Result
```

You can then expand out the nested `DECODE`s and `NVL`s to:

```sql
Select CASE CASE
            WHEN tab.id IS NULL OR tab.id = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END
            +
            CASE
            WHEN tab2.id IS NULL OR tab2.id = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END,
       WHEN 2 THEN 'two'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'none'
       ELSE CASE CASE
                 WHEN tab2.id IS NULL OR tab2.id = 0 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
                 END
            WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
            ELSE 'NA'
            END
       END AS Result
```

In English:

- Covert each of `tab.id` and `tab2.id` to zero, if their values are either zero or `NULL`, or to one and then add the two values together.
- If their total is zero or two then return the total in words.
- If their total is one then check the `tab2.id` value on its own and if its value is not zero or `NULL` then return (in words) `one`.
- Otherwise, it must have been `tab.id` that was not zero or `NULL` and return `NA`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I understood now the functionality of this query and I tried with nested case statement and getting expected results.